# Change the color of yammer embedded in sharepoint.

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, yammer

```
<div id="embedded-feed" style="height:800px;width:400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

yam.connect.embedFeed({
  "config": {
    "use_sso": false,
    "header": false,
    "footer": false,
    "showOpenGraphPreview": false,
    "defaultToCanonical": false,
    "hideNetworkName": false,
    "defaultGroupId": 8430003
  },
  "container": "#embedded-feed"
});

</script>
```

How would I insert CSS into it in order to change the color?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909396/how-to-personalize-yammer-embed-box

Comment: @Michael, I think I gave you the proper information for it.

Answer (score 1):

I already gave you the answer for the same with below description before.

> Yammer doesn't allow you to customize the look & feel of their embed
>   feed. But you can turn off the header via configuration option.
>
> Also that blue background is coming from your network configuration.
>   The same color as your web version, and you can change it inside
>   Network configuration page.
>
> Kindly check the answer at below link.
>
> [How to personalize Yammer embed box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909396/how-to-personalize-yammer-embed-box)